# Calculated moisture in air is greater than maximum

Tags: thermodynamics

I am working with one old report, they calculate parameters of moist air at **46.4F** and pressure **9.5150 lbf/in2, 100% humidity**. They calculate density of air from the state equation and take the density of water vapor from the steam table. Then they find the mass of water vapor like this: Mwv = M * Rowv / Roa
As a result they have the **0.010336 lbm per lbm**:
[image]

**This is greater than maximum** as I can see from this chart:
[image]

I do the same in the MS Excel by VBA:

```
Psat_wv2 = pSatW(T2_k) * sf1  'saturated vapor pressure from the table

Pwv2 = Psat_wv2

Pa2 = P2 - Pwv2
Roa2 = Pa2 * 144 / (R * T2_r)

ds2 = densSatVapTW(T2_k) * sf2  'density of saturated steam from the table

Rowv2 = ds2

Mwv2 = Ma * Rowv2 / Roa2
```

And I get **the same** results. Ma is 1 lbm.

*I understand that I can calculate it another way or simply take the number from the table but it is interesting for me what happens here because the same logic is used in another places of this report.*

Comment: You know that your chart only goes up to 90% humidity, right?  Do you want me to show you how to work out, for your conditions, where the point would be at 100 % humidity

Comment: Seems like it is 8 C, there can be only 7.5 gr / kg, but they have 10

Comment: You are aware that 9.50 psi is only about 2/3 atm, and the tool box chart is for 1.0 atm. (14.7 psi), right?  So there is only about 2/3 as much air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 8 C, the equilibrium vapor pressure of water is 1070 Pa.  At 9.5150 psi, the total pressure in Pa is $\frac{9.5150}{14.7}(101325)=65586\ Pa$ So the partial pressure of the air is 65586 - 1070 = 64515 Pa.  So the moles of water vapor per mole of dry air is 1070/64515=0.0166.  The mass of water vapor per mass of dry air is $(0.0166)\frac{18}{29}$=0.0103.

If the total pressure were 1 atm., the ratio would be 0.66, in agreement with the chart.

Comment: Does it mean that at lower pressure the air can keep greater mass of water vapor per mass of dry air ?

Comment: That seems to be a valid interpretation.